# STM32 debugger and prints disable interrupts

Tags: stm32, interrupt, uart

I am using an STM32F767ZI board to interface with an NEO-6M GPS module. The problem I'm having is easy to explain, but I cannot figure out what's causing it.

In my setup, I receive UART data from the neo6m module using USART2 10 bytes at a time, then I buffer it for a bit, and when enough data is accumulated I then print it out to the UART4 port, 5 bytes a time (the reasons for this are related to what i intend to do in the future) where I can see the data that the neo6m module outputs. I am using any interrupt for the data reception, and in the ISR i write to a circular buffer.
Nominally, everything works well, the data gets sent to me exactly how I want it. Despite this, when I put a breakpoint or a uart print inside the ISR, the ISR stops getting triggered after the first run and i no longer receive any data. Another strange symptom is that after uploading code to the board I cannot receive any data from the neo6m, only when I reset it using the black button does it start working. What influence could putting a breakpoint or a print msg inside the ISR on whether or not it gets triggered in the future? (The print was only for debugging purposes I dont intend on keeping it there).

My code is as follows (Feel free to comment on my approach to interrupt based uart reception)

```
* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
#define UART_RX_INCREMENT 10
#define UART_RX_SAFETY_MARGIN 100
/*NEO_6M_UART_TRIGGER must be enough to hold one complete batch from neo6m,
to make sure that a full GPGGA msg is there. To reduce this size, the gps needed to be configured to
only output gpgga msgs */
#define NEO_6M_UART_TRIGGER 750
#define NEO_6M_DATA_SIZE 5
#define NEO_6M_BUFFER_MSGS 2

static lwrb_t Neo6mUartRingBuf;
static uint8_t Neo6mUartBuf[NEO_6M_UART_TRIGGER*NEO_6M_BUFFER_MSGS];
static uint8_t Uart2RxBuf[UART_RX_INCREMENT];

static volatile atomic_bool Neo6mDataReadyFlag = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(false);
static volatile atomic_bool Neo6mUartRingBufBusy = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(false);

static uint8_t Neo6mDataBuf[NEO_6M_DATA_SIZE];

size_t Stm32_IORead(void* DataPtr, size_t ReadSize)
{
    atomic_store_explicit(&Neo6mUartRingBufBusy, true, memory_order_seq_cst);
    size_t ReadBytes = lwrb_read(&Neo6mUartRingBuf, DataPtr, ReadSize);
    atomic_store_explicit(&Neo6mUartRingBufBusy, false, memory_order_seq_cst);
    return ReadBytes;
}

int main(void)
{
 
  HAL_Init();

  lwrb_init(&Neo6mUartRingBuf, Neo6mUartBuf, sizeof(Neo6mUartBuf)); /* Initialize buffer */

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_UART4_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, Uart2RxBuf, UART_RX_INCREMENT);

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
    if (atomic_load_explicit(&Neo6mDataReadyFlag, memory_order_acquire))
    {
        int ReadBytes = Stm32_IORead(Neo6mDataBuf,NEO_6M_DATA_SIZE);
        while (ReadBytes == NEO_6M_DATA_SIZE)
        {
        //handle data
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart4, Neo6mDataBuf, NEO_6M_DATA_SIZE, 100);
        ReadBytes = Stm32_IORead(Neo6mDataBuf,NEO_6M_DATA_SIZE);
        }
        atomic_store_explicit(&Neo6mDataReadyFlag, false, memory_order_seq_cst); //This race condition is not a serious problem, since it only causes 10B to be added */
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}


void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    size_t FreeBytes;
    HAL_StatusTypeDef status;

    FreeBytes = lwrb_get_free(&Neo6mUartRingBuf);
    if (FreeBytes < UART_RX_SAFETY_MARGIN)
    {
        if (!atomic_load_explicit(&Neo6mUartRingBufBusy, memory_order_acquire))
        {
            lwrb_reset(&Neo6mUartRingBuf);
        }
    }

    lwrb_write(&Neo6mUartRingBuf, Uart2RxBuf, UART_RX_INCREMENT);

    if (lwrb_get_full(&Neo6mUartRingBuf) >= NEO_6M_UART_TRIGGER )
    {
        atomic_store_explicit(&Neo6mDataReadyFlag, true, memory_order_seq_cst);
    }

    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, Uart2RxBuf, UART_RX_INCREMENT);
}
```

What could possibly be the issue?